# How to stop user from entering empty date in react form?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement a form that stops the user from not choosing a date in the form. Here is what I tried so far and doesn't work(the user can select no date at all and the form will still be submitted:

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
  name: null,
  date: null
});

const { name, date } = inputs;

// And inside the form:
<div className="form-group">
  <label>Date appointment: </label>
  <input type="date" name="date" onInput={handleChange} value={date} />
  {submitted && date === null && (
    <div className="invalid-feedback">Appointment date is required</div>
  )}
</div>;
```

I tried to with date initialized at `""` and `!date` as the condition and it still doesn't work. How to accomplish this simple functionality? It works with all the other fields of the form.

Comment: you can set disabled property of an input field

Answer (score 0):

you can use disabled property of an Input field

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
  name: null,
  date: null
});

const { name, date} = inputs;

// And inside the form:
<div className="form-group">
   <label>Date appointment: </label>
   <input
     type="date"
     name="date"
     onInput={handleChange}
     value={date} 
     disabled={date === null ? true : false}
   />
   {submitted && date === null && (
      <div className="invalid-feedback">Appointment date is required</div>
   )}

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to prevent submitting of form before filling out all the required fields, here is a fixed sample from your code:

```
function FormTest() {
  const [date, setDate] = React.useState("");
  const isSubmittable = () => (date ? true : false);

  const handleOnChange = (event) => setDate(event.target.value);

  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label>Date appointment: </label>
      <input type="date" name="date" onInput={handleOnChange} value={date} />
      <button disabled={!isSubmittable()}>Submit!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Suggestion:** that's better to use a form state manager like [react-form-hook](https://react-hook-form.com/) or [Formik](https://formik.org/) to implement forms.